# The Function (fn) key keeps bringing up Mission Control. How do I disable it?

Tags: mac, keyboard, mission-control

(fn) Function Key keeps bringing up Mission Control. How do I disable it? I have looked all around and have found no answers? any ideas?

Comment: The fn key at the lower left of the keyboard by itself is invoking Mission Control?

Comment: @Daniel Yes it does. If you see my post below I gave some more info about the settings. Not sure where I can deactivate this. It is ironic that I can't find an easy fix to this. Most likely the setting is in some random place just need to locate it.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to replicate the problem. Here's what worked on my machine to fix it:

- Go to System Preferences » Mission Control
- Under `Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts`, go to `Mission Control`.

  - If it's set to `fn`, set it to some other value (or the `-` at the bottom of the list to disable a keyboard shortcut for Mission Control).
  - If it's not set for `fn`, but `fn` keeps triggering it (which happened to me), change it to anything else, then change it back to the value you want it to have.

On my machine, that made `fn` stop triggering Mission Control.

Comment: This answer solved the problem for me. Thanks! The first answer does not address the actual question/problem.

Comment: It's 2022, this bug still exists and this workaround still works.

Answer (score 2):

To disable the functions of all Fn keys you can go to Apple > System Preferences. Then click on **Keyboard** and check the box that says *"Use all F1, F2, keys as standard function keys"*

As for jsut Mission Control you can go to in System Preferences to **Mission Control**, and you'll find there some list menus that let you choose the keys for the different features of Mission Control. At the bottom there is a "-" which turns it off.

Comment: That does not disable "all Fn functions" by far. I use Fn in tandem with nearly every key on my keyboard. That preference only changes the behavior of the Function (F1-F12) key row, and otherwise does nothing to the Fn button.